# has_one still returning nil after updating belongs_to counterpart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model with `has_one :designpad`, a designpad model with `belongs_to :user` and the column `user_id`.

Now I do this:

```
u = User.first
d = Designpad.new
d.user_id = u.id
d.save

d.user # returns the user (== u)
u.designpad # always returns nil, but why?
```

Why does `u.designpad` return nil? `u.methods` lists the methods `designpad` and `designpad=`, just as expected while using a `has_one` association.

But `u.designpad` just won't return the expected designpad.

Comment: try reloading user object with u.reload

Comment: You should assign the `designpad` to the `user` via the association as per @fl00r's answer, rather than assign to the `user_id` field directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @keymone said, the problem that your `u` object is not reloaded. Also you can refactor your code a little:

```
u = User.first
d = user.create_designpad
# Check:
d.user
#=> u
u.designpad
#=> d
```